# Problem with save cyrillics data to sqlexpress database

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-express

I am using .net entity framework, asp.net mvc, sqlexpress and have one problem:

when save data to sqlexpress database table (something like this `само да пробам`) on that table I have this ???? ?? ??????. On column where insert cyrillics data I set collation:Serbian_Cyrillic_100_CI_AI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datatype of the column should be nvarchar (which is Unicode).

Comment: `@Richard Schneider`: I'm using text not nvarchar. Is nvarchar good replacement for text data type

Comment: @user - Yes. `text` is deprecated but this isn't entirely the correct answer. You can store it in a non unicode column fine as long as the collation is set correctly but need to avoid it getting cast to your database's default collation. `CREATE TABLE #T (C TEXT COLLATE Serbian_Cyrillic_100_CI_AI); INSERT INTO #T VALUES (N'само да робам'); SELECT * FROM #T`

Comment: Actually, if you want Unicode-capability, use `NTEXT` - or better yet (since TEXT/NTEXT are deprecated): `NVARCHAR(MAX)`